# I need to get two numbers of a string like like this "5+7", but when im using .split(\\+) only get the first, how can i get both?

Tags: java, string, split

```
String x = "5+7";
String []n = x.split("\\+");

System.out.println(n[0]); //  =5
System.out.println(n[1]); //  =\
```

Comment: Are you sure that your code doesn't work?

Comment: it actually works.. http://ideone.com/xnGnj1

Comment: @Droidman I don't think the code will work in the state it currently is in because of the broken comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work fine, but I'd try to make it more robust:

```
  String test = "5 + 7";
  String[] tokens = test.split("\\s*\\+\\s*");

  for (String token : tokens) {
     System.out.println(token);
  }
```

The `\\s*` will allow for possible white-space between the numbers and the `+` char.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
x.split("[+]");
```

That will split it correctly.

Comment: How is this better than the original poster's code?

Comment: I get this error when I used x.split("[+]");

5---this is n[0]
but in n[1] shows this error

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1